# Obtener valor Result de un Subscribe en Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, express

Hola que tal he intentado obtener el valor que arroja al momento de llamar un servicio, pero de del susbcribe me los muestra pero no los puedo usar despues ya que me eliminina las variables que ahi tengo con esos valores, este seria mi codigo que estoy utilizando

```
  cedisTodos() {
  return this._cedisService.verTodosCedis(this.token).subscribe(
    response => {
      if(!response){
        this.message = global.errorServidor;
        this._snackBar.open(this.message, global.messageCorrecto,  {
          duration: 5000,
        });
      }else{
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response.cedis);
        console.log(response.cedis);
        return this.prueba = response.cedis;
      }
    },
    error => {
      var errorMessage = <any>error;
      var body = error.error.message;
      if(errorMessage != null){
        this.message = body;
        this._snackBar.open(this.message, global.messageCorrecto,  {
          duration: 5000,
        });
      }
    },
  );
```

}

Lo que necesito obtener es lo que muestro en el return this.prueba pero cuando lo mando a llamar donde lo necesito me dice que esta undefinied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No regreses nada, sólo asigna tus valores en variables a nivel de clase.

```
// Esta variable a nivel de declaración de variables de clase
public prueba;

// Tu función no debería regresar nada, ya que es una suscripción asíncrona
cedisTodos(): void {
    this._cedisService.verTodosCedis(this.token)
    .subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
            if (!response) {
                this.message = global.errorServidor;
                this._snackBar.open(this.message, global.messageCorrecto, {
                    duration: 5000,
                });
            } else {
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response.cedis);
                // Aquí solo asigna el valor llegado a tu variable declarada
                this.prueba = response.cedis;
                console.log( this.prueba );
            }
        },
        ( error: any ) => {
            let errorMessage = <any>error;
            let body = error.error.message;
            if(errorMessage != null){
                this.message = body;
                this._snackBar.open(this.message, global.messageCorrecto,  {
                duration: 5000,
                });
            }
        })
}
```

Así ya tienes la data, sin necesidad de retornar o esperar la respuesta del servidor, puesto que es un observable. Pon atención a los comentarios que te puse. No debería haber error, si lo hay, sería mínimo, algo que puedes solucionar solo.

**AGREGO**

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.cedisTodos();
}
```

La función `ngOnInit` no debería tener un `console.log` de la variable, puesto que se ejecuta de forma lineal, y la función aún no termina de procesar.

Es como si quieras tomarte una taza de café y antes de poner el agua ya le estas tomando a la taza.

Comment: No me ocasiono ningún problema y agradezco tu ayuda, ahora que lo tengo como me lo pusiste necesito saber donde debo de llamar la función ya que lo tengo en el **ngOnInit** y abajo de llamar la función trato de mostrar el valor de this.prueba pero sigue mostrándome **undefinid**

Comment: Ya te agregué un código adicional que te puede ayudar, agregué un `console.log` en la función que estas invocando